# Find a single number in a list of integers: Not working for negative integers

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code to find the only integer in a list which appears only once while all other appear 3 times. The code works fine for positive integers, but have problem with negative integers.

Can anyone help me fix it? Thanks.

```
class Solution:
    # @param A, a list of integer
    # @return an integer
    def singleNumber(self, A):
        if(A==None):
            return None
        else:
            s=[0]*32
            ans=0
            for i in range(len(s)):
                for j in A[:]:
                    if (j>>i)&1:
                        s[i] +=1
                s[i]=s[i]%3
                ans |= (s[i]<<i)
        return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

`collections.Counter` is useful for this kind of thing and won't choke on negative numbers.

```
>>> import collections
>>> l = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
>>> c = collections.Counter(l).items()
>>> [k for k, v in c if v == 1][0]
2
>>> l = [-i for i in l]
>>> c = collections.Counter(l).items()
>>> [k for k, v in c if v == 1][0]
-2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def getSingle( arr, n):
        ones = 0
        twos = 0
        for i in range(0,n):
            twos  = twos | (ones & arr[i]);
            ones  = ones ^ arr[i];
            common_bit_mask = ~(ones & twos);
            ones = ones & common_bit_mask;
            twos = twos & common_bit_mask;
        return ones;
```

Works for negative numbers too.

https://ideone.com/365Iie